# How to align things responsive html CSS

Tags: css, html, responsive-design

What I have ::

[image]

What I need ::

[image]

The first image is what I have, while the second is what I'm supposed to do. It's supposed to be responsive, but I'm finding it quite hard to align both sections.

I have this for **Html** & **CSS** ::

```css
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.uno {
  background-color: #009B76;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 36px
}
.uno img {
  margin: 4px;
}
.contenedor2 {
  width: 77%;
  display: flex;
  display: flex !important;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center !important;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}
.dos img {
  margin-top: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 42px;
}
.contenedor3 {
  max-width: 51%;
  width: 77%;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  align-items: center !important;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <div class="flex-item uno">
    <img src="farmasalogo.png">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="contenedor2">
  <div class="flex-item dos">
    <img src="circulo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="contenedor3">
    <div class="flex-item tres">
      <label>Farmacia:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname">
      <br>
      <label>Sucursal:</label>
      <input type="text" name="lastname1">
      <br>
      <label>Tipo de Farmacia:</label>
      <select>
        <option>Select an Option</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm really stuck on this one, so I could really use the help. Thank you all very much.

Comment: Can anyone please edit the question and add the images in question as i.imgur.com is banned at my end. Thank you

Comment: Seems like you go on the right way ... what it's the problem ? the align for labels and inputs ?

Comment: @DaniP, yes that's exactly my problem. Those have to be aligned responsively, but I can't seem to be able to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Concept:** Switch between `display: block` (the default) and `display: table` by using media queries. I believe this same tactic can be used to switch to `display: flex` too, if you'd like.

**Example:** Run the snippet below in full-screen mode to see the effect(s) and then review the code. (Pay extra attention to any rules starting with `.form`)

```css
/* Default and extra small devices (portrait phones, less than 34em) */
html,
body {
  margin: 0em;
  padding: 0em;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: white;
}

.header {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.page-header {
  background-color: #009B76;
}

.page-section {
  margin: 0em auto;
  margin-top: 2em;
  padding: 2em;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.section-header {
  margin-top: -1.5em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.form {
  display: block;
}

.form-control-wrapper {
  display: block;
}

.form-label {
  margin-top: 1.5em;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.form-label,
.form-control {
  display: block;
}

.form-control {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #BBB;
  background-color: transparent;
}

/* Small devices (landscape phones, 34em and up) */
@media (min-width: 34em) {

  .page-section {
    max-width: 30em;
  }

  .form {
    display: table;
    margin: 0em auto;
  }

  .form-control-wrapper {
    display: table-row;
  }

  .form-label {
    padding-right: 1.5em;
  }

  .form-label,
  .form-control {
    display: table-cell;
  }

}

/* Medium devices (tablets, 48em and up) */
@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .page-section {
    max-width: 44em;
  }
}

/* Large devices (desktops, 62em and up) */
@media (min-width: 62em) {
  .page-section {
    max-width: 58em;
  }
}

/* Extra large devices (large desktops, 75em and up) */
@media (min-width: 75em) {
  .page-section {
    max-width: 71em;
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header page-header">
  <img src="farmasalogo.png">
</header>
<section class="page-section">
  <header class="header section-header">
    <img src="circulo.png">
  </header>
  <form class="form">
    <div class="form-control-wrapper">
      <label class="form-label" for="pharmacy-field">Farmacia:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="pharmacy" id="pharmacy-field">
    </div>

    <div class="form-control-wrapper">
      <label class="form-label"  for="branch-field">Sucursal:</label>
      <input class="form-control" type="text" name="branch" id="branch-field">
    </div>

    <div class="form-control-wrapper">
      <label class="form-label" for="pharmacy-type-field">Tipo de Farmacia:</label>
      <select class="form-control" id="pharmacy-type-field">
        <option>Select an Option</option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

(My breakpoints and general coding style are either taken directly from or inspired by [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), which may also provide similar [and probably better] responsive solutions)

**Other notes**: I would recommend using a `<form>` tag in your HTML (as I did in my example) so it's easier to submit all of the data when you get there. Also, ems come highly recommended as the unit of choice. Finally, I added the `for=""` attribute to the `<label>` tags. This is a really easy habit to form (no pun intended) and helps provide better accessibility on your sites.

If you have any further questions, leave me a comment. Hope that helps!

Comment: No problem! If this answer is sufficient, please mark it as "accepted".
(And welcome to StackOverflow!)

Comment: Done, and thank you. I think I only have one final question. The designer in my team is asking if I can make the inputs a tad bigger. I tried playing around with this, but the responsive stops working if I do.

Comment: Nope, sorry - I figured it out. Once again, thanks for everything!

Comment: Glad this helped. Best of luck on the project!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `<br>` tags. You basically need a structure like this. The `.contenedor2` class has a `flex-direction: column` and each containing `.row` item has a `flex-direction: row`.

```
<div class="contenedor2">
  <div class="head">
    <img src="circulo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Farmacia:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Sucursal:</label>
    <input type="text" name="lastname1">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <label>Tipo de Farmacia:</label>
    <select>
      <option>Select an Option</option>
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  ....
</div>
```

With CSS basically something like this

```
.contenedor2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.contenedor2 .row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.contenedor2 .row label {
    width: 300px;
    flex: 0 0;
}
```

Comment: I created three containers (contenedor1, contenedor2, and contenedor3). I did the third container so it would be easier to align the <input>'s, which is basically all I need. When I do what you suggested, however, all I get is this: http://i.imgur.com/luJt1nW.png I'm sorry, I can't upload images yet</a>.